# Multiple “Disk not ejected properly” messages during sleep

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, usb, sleep-wake, external-disk

When I hook up a WD My Book 3TB external hard drive to my 2016 MacBook Pro via a third party USB-C to USB-A hub and let the computer sleep during the night, this is what I’m greeted with the next morning (see image, Norwegian OS). What gives? Which compoonent should I blame? I can also hear the drive at night spinning up and spinning down continuously.

[image: Multiple “Disk not ejected properly” notifications]

Comment: Are you running a backup utility? like Carbon Copy Cloner.

Comment: translate to english please `los ut my book for den kobles fra eller slas av`

Comment: @jmhI I am running Backblaze!

Comment: @Buscar웃 It translates to “Eject “My Book” before disconnecting or turning it off."

Comment: thank you, so it is telling you to Eject before it goes to sleep

Comment: @Buscar웃 Well, I know what the notification is trying to tell me, but the issue is that this shouldn’t happen when the drive is connected during sleep. It did not happen previously, and macOS is smart enough to let the computer back up to Time Machine during sleep.

Comment: You are right, it should keep the connection alive. So what is your setup in the Power mode.